# Ubuntu + Error: Failed to run "ant -version", make sure you have ant installed and added to your PATH

Tags: android, ionic-framework

In my Ubuntu 12.04, I am trying to install ionic framework but get some error while running the command **ionic build android**.

I saw a lot of option to set environment variable and got little bit success but even though I am not able to resolve it.

**echo $PATH**

> /usr/bin/node:/home/sainath/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin:/home/sainath/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@global/bin:/home/sainath/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/sainath/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java:/usr/local/ant/bin:/home/sainath/.rvm/bin:/home/sainath/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools:/home/sainath/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools:/home/sainath/.rvm/bin:/home/sainath/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools:/home/sainath/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools:/home/sainath/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java:/usr/local/ant/bin

At last line, it show ant add to the bashrc file

**sudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc**

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:${ANT_HOME}/bin
```

**java -version**

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.1) (7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

**node --version**

```
v0.10.32
```

New error :-

> /home/sainath/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698:
>   Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/home/sainath/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/aapt"
>   (in directory
>   "/home/sainath/MobileApps/myFirstIonicApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib"):
>   error=2, No such file or directory

Still get the error. Please suggest some thing .. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- can you try `java -version` see if java binary is available, if not fix your `JAVA_HOME` or export the correct path to java binary in `PATH`
- make sure `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` if you have x64 linux
- nodejs and ant needs to be on path

Comment: Please see the updated question, added with Java version. Sorry dnt get your point.

Comment: doesn't your JAVA_HOME needs to be `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre` leave out /bin/java ?

Comment: i do not see nodejs on your path...try running `node --version`, update PATH with nodejs location.

Comment: New error come out - Please have a look at question

Comment: do you have ia32-libs ? `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` see my update please

Answer (score 1):

Atlast after a lot of Googling, Problem resolved.

Command : **$sudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc**

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:${ANT_HOME}/bin
export PATH=/usr/bin/node:$PATH
```

Command : **source /etc/bash.bashrc** to reload the file.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1 libstdc++6:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386
```

Now I am able to run command **ionic build android**

Comment: Worked for me. But instead of `export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant`, I set `export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant`.

Comment: @colares : Thanks for addition.